# Why does read from variable give blank new variable?

Tags: bash, variable, echo, read

I am trying to get a folder name from a stored variable string.
When I ran the following

```
path="Folder%20Name/Dir/File"
read -d "/" folder < <(echo ${path/\%20/ })
echo "$folder"
```

I am getting a blank `echo $folder`. Where am I going wrong, I have tried `read -d "/" folder <<< $"(${path/\%20/ })"` with no sucess

Comment: I get `Folder Name`.

Comment: I just realized I was running it in a script and then doing echo outside the script. That was what was causing the blanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first command works just fine on Bash 4.4:

```
$ path="Folder%20Name/Dir/File"
$ read -d "/" folder < <(echo ${path/\%20/ })
$ echo "$folder"
Folder Name
```

Though using process substitution here is unnecessary, you could just use a here-string instead:

```
$ read -d "/" folder <<< "${path/\%20/ }"
```

As for your second command, you're using the localization quoting `$"..."`, which I don't think you need here, and the parenthesis also get added to the string, so you'd get `(Folder Name` if you did that with the `path` variable.

<sub>(as an aside, if you ever start using Zsh, don't use `path` as the name of a variable.)</sub>